# How do I defeat 75 zombies within 25 seconds?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

In the Wild West area, for the first star on day 6, you have to defeat 75 zombies within 25 seconds.  However, there aren't 75 zombies in the last 25 seconds.

What should I do?

Comment: Are questions asking for tips even allowed? O_O

Comment: @Merja99 - Yes they are.  Jim - you'll need to be a bit more specific - day 6 on which part of the game (Egypt / Pirate / Old West) and which star on day 6 is this occurring?

Comment: There is only one challenge for 75 zombies in 25 seconds (Wild West, day 6, star 1), so the question is specific enough.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I just keep trying and try to kill faster on last 25 seconds. I did it.

So basically just before the final wave I spend plant food to bombard them with as much watermellon as possible. Once the final wave is out, I bombard them again with watermellon food. Looks like I reached 75.

The voted up answer is wrong. Yes, you don't have to kill it at the last 25 seconds. However, there are even less zombies on other periods.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to do this in the last 25 seconds, just *any* 25 seconds.

There are several plants that can do damage to multiple zombies when assisted by
plant food.

The best time is during a wave, put some bonk choys on row 2 and 4 right in the middle of the pack and give them both plant food.

Comment: and also, remember that chickens counts towards the zombie limit.  Personally, instead of bonk choys I use snapdragons and plant food, same result really, things within a 3x3 square dies.

Comment: I have the same question, because killing a wave quickly isn't my problem. The lightning reeds take care of the chickens, and I slaughter the rest of them as they come in, but I can't get enough kills. (By contrast, the "100 zombies in 30 seconds" star was easy.)
Obviously the chickens are the key, and I wonder if I'm killing the wranglers _too_ fast, because it's possible to kill them before they let their chickens go (saw a buttered one die without chickens getting loose). But I can't find the right combination/balance/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

The best tactics are (separately or in combination):

1. Use plants that slow down zombies
2. Use plants that hurt several zombies at once
3. BUT does not kill too quickly, since you must allow the Chicken Wrangler Zombie to release all his chickens before killing him - for the chickens is where the count of 75 arrives.

The best plant for this in general is, of cource, Winter Melon. It does all 3 things at once, and can also be helpful when killing the remainder of zombies quickly when given plant food.

The second best plant, given that many of the zombies to be killed are chickens, is the best quick-chicken-slaughter plant known to mankind - Lightning Reed in numbers.

```
 1. |  |BO|
 2. |WM|LR|LR|LR|
 3. |WM|LR|LR|
 4. |WM|LR|LR|LR|
 5. |  |BO|
```

*Note that Coconut Cannon fulfills #2, but fails miserably at #3! So don't bother with it.*

---

**The specific way I passed that challenge is made sure that I had 3 Winter Melons in the 3 middle rows, before the start of the last wave; supplemented by as many Lightning Reeds as you can fit - my setup had 8 of them packed also in 2 middle rows.** See my diagram above.

This was enough to effortlessly kill 75 zombies.

---

If the above ALMOST takes you there but you need an extra oomph,

1. use the trick that the previous answer mentioned, add some throw-away close-distance hitters (Bok Choy) near the zombie entrance points.
2. Add some Boomerangs on the rows #1 and #5 - they are also great at killing chickens. I used them.

Answer (score 0):

Build a row of potatoes towards the right of the screen, a row of snapdragons behind and use the absolute minimum of shooters, (preferably corn shooters due to slowing qualities). The result is a build up of zombies at the potatoes. When the last wave comes feed as many snapdragons as you can and it's a zombie apocalypse. You can also plant spikey plants in font of the potatoes if you have time/sun.

Answer (score -1):

I used the pea pod and the spikerrock and set up 5 double sunflowers so you can get enough suns and you will have no problems.

Comment: its a little too vague.